# How to Weigh MySQL search results on Multiple Columns in Table

Tags: mysql

I'm currently developing a website that needs to Search a Database Table, `books_for_sale`, for a match against the following fields: `isbn_10`,`isbn_13`,`name`,`author`,`publisher`,`description`.

Each field needs to be weighted so that the results can be SortedBy by relevance.

I'd like to use the following relevance multipliers:

```
`isbn` = $searchTerm (30 relevance factor)
`isbn` LIKE $searchTerm% (25 relevance factor)

`name` = $searchTerm (20 relevance factor)
`name` LIKE $searchTerm% (15 relevance factor)
`name` LIKE %$searchTerm% (10 relevance factor)

`author` LIKE $searchTerm (22 relevance factor)
`author` LIKE $searchTerm% (14 relevance factor)
`author` LIKE %$searchTerm% (1 relevance factor)

`description` LIKE %$searchTerm% (2 relevance factor)
`publisher` LIKE %$searchTerm% (1 relevance factor)
```

Current Table SQL:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `books_for_sale`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books_for_sale` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `seller_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isbn_10` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `isbn_13` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `name` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `condition_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `publisher` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `isbn_10` (`isbn_10`),
  KEY `isbn_13` (`isbn_13`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `author` (`author`),
  KEY `seller_id` (`seller_id`),
  KEY `publisher` (`publisher`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I've tried to Google and search for different features, but wasn't getting the best of luck at finding anything useful. If anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it as I'm still new to the more advanced MySQL features.

P.S. If I should restructure my table to better support this type of search features please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

This is a valid syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM books_for_sale

ORDER BY   30 * (`isbn_10` = '$searchTerm')
         + 30 * (`isbn_13` = '$searchTerm')
         + 25 * (`isbn_10` LIKE '$searchTerm%')
         + 25 * (`isbn_13` LIKE '$searchTerm%')
         + 20 * (`name` = '$searchTerm')
         + ...
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a935/3

Note that this just an expression, so this will execute as well:

```
SELECT books_for_sale.* ,
(
    30 * (`isbn_10` = '$searchTerm')
  + 30 * (`isbn_13` = '$searchTerm')
  + 25 * (`isbn_10` LIKE '$searchTerm%')
  + 25 * (`isbn_13` LIKE '$searchTerm%')
  + 20 * (`name` = '$searchTerm')
  + ...
) as `relevance`

HAVING `relevance` > 10
ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
```

Comment: Is it possible to do all that in the WHERE so I can store the relevance value as `rel` and can just do OrderBy `rel` or quickly change it to OrderBy `author` or 1 of the other fields?

Comment: @Steven10172 this is an ordinary expression. As long as you regard the rules for alias visibility, you are good: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a935/7

Comment: I don't see a way to define aliases in a where clause.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the general syntax. I should now be able to complete this feature

Comment: Should Now* (was a typo) @Jan Dvorak